# creating subdomain(sub.domain.com) and redirecting to another server (sub.domain.org) whiles maintaining .com in the url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

**Redirecting to different server but same domain.**
I have 2 servers on different hosts. One has domain.com and the other domain.org. domain.org has more resources. Now i want to create a sub domain on the first one (sub.domain.com) and redirect to (sub.domain.org) whiles maintaining the .com in the urls.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what's your hosting running on (Apache, nginx etc...).
In nginx you can use proxy_pass to redirect request to another host while still preserving url:
    location / {
    proxy_pass        http://domain.org:80;
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    }
Take look at nginx docs for more info: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule
Or this discussion can be helpful: http://www.webmasterworld.com/apache/4464836.htm
It may be possible to also do this by manipulating DNS records so sub.domain.com is resolved to host where subd.domain.org is running (but you need to handle HTTP Host header in webserver)

Comment: Thanks..taking a look at it now

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do it:

1. You need to create DNS alias aka CNAME record for sub.domain.com for redirecting to sub.domain.org (look here ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record ) for more info). You won't need to do any moves on .com server.
2. You can redirect with web-server configuration. So sub.domain.com will refer to .com server and web-server will redirect it to .org. For example virtual host in apache it will look like that.

   ```
           ServerName sub.domain.com
           Options +FollowSymLinks
           RewriteEngine on
           RewriteRule (.*) http://sub.domain.org/ [R=302,L]
   ```
3. Last way is redirect via website files. For example you can put index.php (if you're using php) and place in it:
4. Or proxy it via web-server like `nginx`. upd. as @intense suggested.

ps. I think 302 is the right variant. Not 301 =)

Comment: interesting too. will take a look. Thanks